# LINQ to xml for xml-rpc

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-rpc

I've a xml like below:

```
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>originTransactionID</name>
            <value>
              <string>23915</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>responseCode</name>
            <value>
              <i4>0</i4>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I want to check if any member has an element with name responseCode and if its there, I want to pick the value.

I can pick it like this:

```
var test = xDocument.Descendants("member").Elements("value").LastOrDefault().Value;
```

Its working because I know the response code is the last element of member, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go. Although the xml is predefined but still is there any better to query this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right since you know that the element which you are looking for is at the last location thus `LastOrDefault` is working in your case but it's obviously not dynamic query for a real-world scenario.

You can use `FirstOrDefault` though to find the first matching element in entire collection and get the value like this:-

```
var test = (string)xDocument.Descendants("member")
             .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element("name") == "responseCode")
             ?.Element("value");
```

[Sample Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GHIryd)

Comment: Thanks, it's checking for null as well. By the way, if I need to select multiple values, will you suggest to repeat the same code for multiple elements or you suggest something else?

Comment: @Badhon - By multiple do you mean all matching names? If so you can use `Where` . If you want to select various elements withing matching tag then use `Select` to project it.

Comment: Yes, for example, lets say I want to select the value of originTransactionID too.

Comment: @Badhon - In that case you can remove the filter, simply project all items like this: - `xDocument.Descendants("member").Select(x => (string)x.Element("value"));` It will return - 23915,0 as _collection of string_.

Comment: I want to select them separately and assign to class properties.

Comment: @Badhon - You can project the class in `Select` itself: `.Select(x => new Test { Name = (string)x.Element("value") })`; It will return `IEnumerable<Test>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XPath query:

```
var xPath = "/methodResponse/params/param/value/struct/member/name[text()='responseCode']/../value/i4";
var value = xDocument.XPathSelectElement(xPath).Value;
```

Notice how `name[text()='responseCode']` is used to pick the right `member` element. This will work even if the sequence of `member` elements are changed or another `member` appears as the last element.